# Make calculations with hexadecimal/decimal numbers

Tags: java

I have the rather simple method `naf`

```
public int naf(int NN, int AA, int FF, int Q) {

    int mike = FF + 0x20 * AA + 0x200 * NN;

    if (Q == 1) {
        mike += 0x4000;
    }
    return mike;
}
```

I can understand that this method accepts 4 integers and returns an integer. In the second line, the calculations are a bit confusing. I feel that the `0x` parts have to do with hexadecimal number format, but the input arguments are in decimal. I have also the feeling that the `0x` may make those calculations doable, but I am not certain.

What does the `0x` offer and how can the method make hexadecimal calculations, when the input is decimal?

Comment: Hexadecimal and decimal are just two ways of representing one number, it doesn't change the actual calculation.

Comment: It's all binary in the end my good man.

Comment: The `0x` is just a way of writing a hex number.  `0xa` and `10` are the same number, and the same calculations can be done on both.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken (from what I remember also on other languages), this "0x" is just to indicate the base of the number you put after. "0x20" would mean "20 in base 16" which is equal to 32 in base 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integer literals in java can be in the form of decimal (eg. `32`), hexadecimal (eg. `0x20`) and octal (eg. `040`). The differences being decimal: no prefix, hexadecimal: prefix `0x` and octal: prefix `0`.

Thus,

```
int mike = FF + 0x20 * AA + 0x200 * NN;
```

is really just

```
int mike = FF + 32 * AA + 512 * NN;
```

Oh and the fact that `FF` is also on "hex form" doesn't matter at all, it's just a method parameter and might as well be called `steven`... :-)

Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as hexadecimal calculations.
You have an integer expression, it is just that in it
two numbers are represented in hexadecimal format.

This

`int mike = FF + 0x20*AA + 0x200 * NN;`

is the same as:

`int mike = FF + 2 * 16 * AA + 2 * 16 * 16 * NN;`

which is the same as:

`int mike = FF + 32 * AA + 512 * NN;`

Comment: I would argue the opposite - that there is no such think as decimal calculations, since all computer calculations are done in binary.  Hexadecimal and decimal are just ways of representing these numbers to users.

Comment: @Trenin I didn't mention decimal calculation anywhere. I wrote 'integer calculation' which I later changed to 'integer expression'.

Answer (score 2):

For a computer it doesn't matter how numbers are presented to you, be it decimal (base 10, as we're naturally familiar with), hexadecimal (base 16), octal (base 8), binary (base 2), you name it (though in Java only octal, decimal and hexadecimal are possible out of the box). Internally they are all stored as binary numbers, that's a series of zeros and ones.

In your code you are free to choose the format you feel most comfortable with. By default the Java compiler assumes you are feeding it decimal numbers, but by prefixing your number either with 0x or only 0 you tell it to interpret them as hexadecimal or octal numbers, respectively.

I suggest you try to read up on numeral systems.

Answer (score 1):

Decimal or hexadecimal only applies when you express literals, e.g.:

```
int a = 0xfa; // hexadecimal notation for literal on the right hand side
int b = 251; // decimal notation for the literal on the right hand side
```

Once the values have been stored in variables the system doesn't care if you used decimal or hexadecimal notation to express the values that you stored:

```
int c = a + b; // numbers are added, regardless of you they were expressed above
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! If I want to print out c, what would the output be?

Comment: If I get it right System.out.println("c=" + c); should give you 502, which is 251 + 251, which is 251 + 0xfa. 0xfa in hexadecimal notation is the same number as 251 in decimal notation.

Comment: Oh sorry, 0xfa is actually 250, so c will be 501, or 251 + 250, or 251 + 0xfa. I don't always get the conversion correct in my head.